# Windows: how to get start tool to override a local start.exe?

Tags: windows-7

The start command has been very handy, but I ran into a problem.

I was looking at an old Role Playing game (Questron II) and how to write maps for it. And it had a file called start.exe. And I have a utility that calls, to edit itself,

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" x.pl
```

So in this directory, it pulls the "start.exe" instead of the Windows start.

Running [Search Everything](http://download.cnet.com/Everything/3000-2379_4-10890746.html) didn't turn up a location for **start.(extension)**.

Now, there are obvious workarounds for this instance, such as just pulling the map files I need to a separate directory.

But I'm more concerned with how I would find start.exe, or start.bat, or whatever its extension is, or if it is protected for a reason.

Thanks!

Comment: The standard `start` command is not a file, it is builtin to CMD like e.g. `cd` and `set`. If the 'utility that calls [start]' uses `cmd` then `cmd` should give the builtin `start` precedence over any file, and it does so for me (although I have 8.1 rather than 7). Otherwise the utility should just run `notepad++` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How I would find start.exe, or start.bat?

The Windows `start` command is an internal command (built into the `cmd` shell):

> **Internal commands**
>
> The Windows CMD shell CMD.exe contains a number of 'internal'
>   commands, additional 'external' commands are also supplied as separate
>   executable files. External commands are generally stored in the
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32 folder, this folder is part of the system PATH .
>
> This arrangement means that both internal and external commands are
>   always available no matter what your current directory happens to be.
>
> ASSOC, BREAK, CALL ,CD/CHDIR, CLS, COLOR, COPY, DATE, DEL, DIR, DPATH,
>   ECHO, ENDLOCAL, ERASE, EXIT, FOR, FTYPE, GOTO, IF, KEYS, MD/MKDIR,
>   MKLINK (vista and above), MOVE, PATH, PAUSE, POPD, PROMPT, PUSHD, REM,
>   REN/RENAME, RD/RMDIR, SET, SETLOCAL, SHIFT, START, TIME, TITLE, TYPE,
>   VER, VERIFY, VOL

Source - [Internal commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html)

Comment: This gives me a lot to look for in the future. I never realized about internal commands. I really appreciate when answers open up more than just my direct question. I've used a lot of these  commands but not all, so, lots to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Given that `START` is an internal command from `CMD.EXE`, you could execute it thru the later.

Reading from the CMD.EXE help, we find out that:

```
Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
```

So you can execute your program with:

```
CMD.EXE /C "START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" x.pl"
```

This way you can assure that what is executed is CMD.EXE, and it executes it's START internal command with the parameters that you want it to have.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate answers like this that help me revisit switches I kind of glossed over when I started.